# Mongoose multi document transactions not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose

i have two documents which are related. i have to save the _id of one document into other document. i am using transactions to update two documents at a time so that the data is not corrupted.

But the problem is documents are not getting update . Here is my code

```
const session = await mongoose.startSession();
session.startTransaction();

try {
    MoneyTransactions.updateMany({
        _id: { $in: [id1,id2 ]}
    }, {
            settledOnImport: importTransaction._id
        }, { session }
    )

    Imports.update(
        { _id: importTransaction._id },
        {
            settledOn: Date.now()
        }, { session })

    await session.commitTransaction()

    return importTransaction;

}

catch (e) {

    return null;

}

finally {
    session.endSession();
}
```

Any thoughts? any alternative is would also be helpful. 
Here are the versions i am using

node version-v10.15.3

mongoose -5.5.4

typescript - ^3.4.4

mongodb -4.0.1

Comment: I ran into the same issue. Did you solve it?

Comment: @goforu i solved it using await statement before the update

Comment: @kirshna weird... It's still not working for me. Got: MongoError: Cannot run command against the 'admin' database in a transaction

Comment: @goforu it is not an admin database for me..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method `MoneyTransactions.updateMany` and `Imports.update` are asynchronous method. Add the keyword `await` in front of them, or you will commit a transaction on nothing.

Comment: MongoError: Cannot run command against the 'admin' database in a transaction.. i am getting this error

Comment: i am running replica set through run-rs

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB currently only supports transactions on replica sets, not standalone servers. Make sure your MongoDb meet the requirements.

Comment: I am using replication set using run-rs. Thanks!